# Two animated sprite overlap with each other,how to only animate upper one?

Tags: android, andengine

Each (total 8) animated sprite's have onAreaTouch() with path,move modifier but problem is that when two sprite's(animated) overlapped or above each other then on touch of these sprite's(onAreaTouch() called) both sprite's animated but i want to animate only first one or upper one.please help me out.

**This is sample code:**

```
AnimatedSprite animatedSprite_1 = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0,tiledTextureRegion_1,getVertexBufferObjectManager())
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) 
            {
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
                {
                   animatedSprite_1.animate();//to animate
                }
            }
        }
    mScene.attachChild(animatedSprite_1);
    mScene.registerTouchArea(animatedSprite_1);
```

Comment: sprites? what sprites?

Comment: what?its animated sprite

Comment: there is no such thing like "animated sprite" in android

Comment: sorry...! it's AnimatedSprite.